# Property 'token' does not exist on type 'Object'. Typescript issue

Tags: angular, typescript

So I'm getting a compiler error stating that token doesn't exist on type Object. This object is getting returned from the server with two objects. A token and a user object. I'm not sure how to define res in the code example below so that typescript is okay with this.

```
return this.http.post(api.url, params)
        .map(res => {
          if (res && res.token) {
              localStorage.setItem('token', res.token);
              localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(res.user));
              return true;
          }

          return false;
        });
```

Comment: use res['token'] instead of res.token. your problem will be solved

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Typescript is complaining the response does not have a property named token, Change it as,

```
return this.http.post(api.url, params)
        .map((res:any) => {
```

Comment: Use of `any` should be minimal, in this case `res` and `res.token` seems to be potentially null/undefined.
It would reduce mistakes to declare it as

`.map((res?: {token?: string, user: object}) => {`

Answer (score 2):

```
 return this.http.post(api.url, params)
    .map(res => {
      if (res && res.token) {
          localStorage.setItem('token', res[‘token’]);
          localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(res[‘user’]));
          return true;
      }

      return false;
    });
```